# Did "Sarkissian" know that Cameron is a robot?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* S01E09 ("What He Beheld"), a person called "Sarkissian" is trying to kill Sarah Connor, John Connor and also Cameron.

[image]

He also plants a car bomb in Cameran's vehicle. Eventually it blows and because of this Cameron was malfunctioning and trying to kill John.

[image]

So my question is, did "Sarkissian" know that Cameron is a robot?